# Online-Quiz: Dividing the answers and questions in to 3 Categories by choosing different Radio-Buttons

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-mobile, slice

I have a problem by updating my Online-Quiz.

I want to Categorize my Questions and Answers by clicking on Radio Buttons.
This is my HTML-Code:

```
<fieldset id="my" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
    <legend>Choose a Category</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-mini" id="radio-mini-1" value="choice-1"  />
    <label for="radio-mini-1">Amateur</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-mini" id="radio-mini-2" value="choice-2"  />
    <label for="radio-mini-2">Middle</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-mini" id="radio-mini-3" value="choice-3"  />
    <label for="radio-mini-3">Legend</label>
</fieldset>

<a href="#" id="Next" data-role="button" onclick="nextStart()">Send</a>
```

So I have 3 Radio Buttons.  These radio buttons have also their own multidimensional arrays.    After I choose one category, the array-name should be renamed to an generally array name "question", because for this array name I have lots of different function which I don`t want to write for every single array. My Javascript-Code after I have clicked on the Send-Button:

```
function nextStart()    
{
//document.getElementById("quiz").submit();

$.mobile.changePage( "quiz.html", 
{
    transition: "pop",
    reverse: false,
    changeHash: false
});


$("input[name=radio-mini]:checked").each(function next() 
{
        if ($(this).val() = "choice-1")
        {
            category = "amateur";   
        }

        else if ($(this).val() = "choice-2")
        {   
            schwierigkeit = "middle";
        }

        else 
        {
            schwierigkeit = "legend";
        }
}); 
}
```

Now I tell my general array "question" from which array it got the informations:

```
    if(category = "amateur")
    {       
        question = amateur.slice(); 
    }

    else if (category = "middle")
    {
        question = middle.slice();
    }

    else
    {
        question = legend.slice();

    }
```

If I click the category 2 or 3 "legend" and then on the Send Button I get only on the next side, the answers and questions from the first array "amateur". 
So I think it doesn't save the right array name after the function

```
nextStart()
```

But I don`t got the solution to fix it.. Can somebody help me?

It would be nice, thanks beforehand :-)

Comment: It's just a typo. You are using `schwierigkeit = "middle"` and `schwierigkeit = "legend"` instead of `category = "middle"` and `category = "legend"`

Comment: Ouh I forgot to rename it. I changed all variable and array names in english, so that everybody can understand it. I just forget to changed these two variable-names, but it`s not the real mistake in the code..

Comment: Well look at the places you are using a single `=` instead of `==` -- is that the problem. For example, `if (category = "amateur") {` should be `if (category == "amateur") {` and same for all the other equality comparisons in your code -- they are all wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben Lee already stated, you are using asignment operator instead of equality. Should be like this:

```
if ($(this).val() == "choice-1") {
    category = "amateur";
}

else if ($(this).val() == "choice-2") {
    category = "middle";
}

else {
    category = "legend";
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZV4s/1/).

#### UPDATE:

I totally missed the following code, which contains the same error. Thanks, Ben!

```
if(category == "amateur")
{       
    question = amateur.slice(); 
}

else if (category == "middle")
{
    question = middle.slice();
}

else
{
    question = legend.slice();

}
```

Comment: Not just there. The operator is also wrong in the top part e.g. `if ($(this).val() = "choice-1")` -- though I'd expect that part to throw an error rather than be a silent tricky bug.

Maybe it *does* throw an error, but it's inconsequential because the latter part always did the same thing because of the `=` instead of `==`

Comment: Strange, I've updated my fiddle to include other part of the code - it's working as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZV4s/2/. Please also make sure that your variables `category` and `question` are global and initialized somewhere (like in my code).

Comment: Jes you are both right, but it doesn`t fixed the mistake. It stil gives me the questions of the first array.. If i change `if ($(this).val() = "choice-1") {` in to `if ($(this).val() == "choice-1") {` , nothing changed. After I changed this : `if(category = "amateur")` in to `if(category == "amateur")`, I don`t get any output.. I think after the function nextStart() the variable name category and its input can not  read later..

Comment: Have you tried updated fiddle from my comment above?

Comment: Jes, but after I deleted the onclick-event and changed the function from `function nextStart ()` to `$('#Next').click(function()`, the Send-Button lost totally its function.. So it actually hasn`t the submit-function to the next site where I can see the question and its answers.

Comment: This change couldn't affect the logic. Here, I've changed it back to `onclick()`: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZV4s/3/. Also make sure that code for navigating to other page is not commented (`$.mobile.changePage`).

Comment: I have also changed it back, if i take this code `if(category == "amateur")
{       
    question = amateur.slice(); 
}... ` outside from the function, the buttons where I get the answers, show me no answers but it shows me now if this answer was right or not, so there is always a mistake at the output but other functions are workable..

Comment: I can't help you further because I don't know your full code. And I think I've answered your original question already.

Comment: I don`t know why and how ,but after I have played a little bit with the code, the code is actually completly workable :D

Comment: So thank you very very much for your help :-) I hope you have a nice Day !:-)